# Using Node.js to push data into Redis

Tags: node.js, redis

I'm trying to write data to redis using Node.js

The client does the following:

```
var Redis = require('redis');

var DataStore = function () {
    var client = this.redisClient = Redis.createClient();
};

DataStore.prototype.appendObject = function (prefix, key, value, callback) {
    // append
    return this.redisClient.push(prefix + ':' + key, [JSON.stringify(value)], function (err) {
        return callback(err, value);
    });
}
```

On trying to write data to by calling appendObject, I get the following error:

```
/Users/foobar/code/node_modules/redis/index.js:602
                throw err;
                  ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at DataStore.appendObject (/Users/foobar/code/lib/data_store.js:41:29)
    at /Users/foobar/code/lib/manager.js:52:35
    at /Users/foobar/code/lib/data_store.js:31:16
    at try_callback (/Users/foobar/code/node_modules/redis/index.js:592:9)
    at RedisClient.return_reply (/Users/foobar/code/node_modules/redis/index.js:685:13)
    at ReplyParser.<anonymous> (/Users/foobar/code/node_modules/redis/index.js:321:14)
    at ReplyParser.emit (events.js:107:17)
    at ReplyParser.send_reply (/Users/foobar/code/node_modules/redis/lib/parser/javascript.js:300:10)
    at ReplyParser.execute (/Users/foobar/code/node_modules/redis/lib/parser/javascript.js:203:22)
    at RedisClient.on_data (/Users/foobar/code/node_modules/redis/index.js:547:27)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Having the same issue, did you ever resolve?